# What is a simple way to lock the content of a webpage?

Tags: password-protection

For example, just requiring a user name `foo` and password `bar`, or user name `foo`, and the password is today's date, take day of month (such as the 16 in Oct 16), multiply by 2 and repeat twice, which is `3232`?

Comment: You should probably add some tags for the operating system, language and which technologies you intended to use, if any. All of these will affect the answer.

Comment: Don't you have any requirements at all? ASP.NET? PHP? Builtin stuff in some obscure webserver?

Comment: Deriving the password from the date is neither secure or simple.  Once someone knows how to derive the password, you'd have to redesign the password protection to keep them out.

Comment: What do you mean by "lock the content"?  Are you trying to restrict access?  Or modifications?

Comment: something like .htaccess i guess, but can its password vary day after day?

Comment: Hey OP, after almost 7 years (and now with lots of reputation under your belt), I'm sure you solved this somehow? Maybe you could hence post an answer to your own question and mark it **accepted** so we can get the question out of the pipeline. Or delete the question. Or edit it with more details so we can finally find an answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pick a hard-to-guess password and just use that. Your web server probably has a method for providing password-protected access and it will almost certainly support as many users as you like.

Remember to think of passwords as simply a shared secret. Your complicated date arithmetic is also a shared secret, but it is fundamentally no more or less secure than a password. If you choose sensible passwords (i.e. not guessable, ideally random) then you don't need to muck around with convoluted schemes.

Comment: I agree the more complicated a protection scheme the more likely it has holes.

Comment: is it apparent this question is not about choose a password?

Comment: No, the question as stated is essentially 'which of these two password schemes should I use'. If that is not the intended question then the author might consider providing a little more detail.

Comment: hm... i thought the title says "What is a simple way to lock..."  It really is about "How to lock" it, rather than "what password to lock it"

Comment: Yes, but the body of the question is "which of these two password systems should I use". In any case, I mentioned that the web server probably provides password-protected access which is the simplest of all locking mechanisms. I stand by my answer that picking a good password is a simple, effective way to lock the content of a web page.